# When would docks on Chatfield Reservoir be least busy with boaters putting in and taking out?

Tags: lakes, colorado, magnet-fishing

I have a magnet and line setup to go magnet fishing and I would like to make some sweeps around one the docks [Chatfield Reservoir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatfield_Reservoir) on where it's likely that people have dropped gear/cellphones into the water, but so far there have always been people there  putting their boat in and out and I don't want to disturb them.

What **time of day/week** would I have the best chance of finding  the docks completely deserted so I can go magnet fishing without bothering anyone?

Comment: Depends where, is there a location in mind?

Comment: Middle of the week, or at times when fishing is known to be "not good" - ie, where I am on the coast low tide is the wrong time to fish.  Incoming tide and up to the tide change to outgoing is best.  So for my local pier, I'd do it during the week at low tide :)

Comment: @Aravona A specific location would be too localized, and I am really just looking for general suggestions

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh I think this will always depend on a few local/seasonal factors so will always change - do the docks/piers have commercial traffic? (ferries, dayboating) Is there private mooring? (So you can't go there anyway) Is it a tourist hotspot? (School holidays etc likely to be busier?)

Comment: @Aravona I bet the answer is just go early in the morning on a weekday and no more complicated than that. If I have to put one specific location I may as well delete because then this question really is of no use

Comment: The most correct answer is 3AM on a dark and stormy night.  Obviously not the best answer, I think this should stay closed.as by the time you narrow it to be helpful it is going to be more localized then the OP is aiming for.

Comment: This answer could be answered as 'What are some factors that affect how busy fishing spots are?" or "What factors affect how good the fishing is for a specific area?" - not direct answers, but appropriate for Q&A and would provide information for someone seeking to answer the original question.

Comment: Is it really necessary to put this on hold?  This question can be answered and I don't see how leaving it open hurts anything.

Comment: @Qudit it is a question of scope creep and relative value to the site.  The OP is generating questions for the benefit of the site (as I also do) sometimes what seems like a good question when you write it, ultimately is not.  That is why the voting process exists, the community decides.  If you think the question ads value to the site, vote to open it.  If enough people agree then it will be re-opened.  I don't think the OP is going to take it personally either way.

Comment: @Aravona Added location

Comment: @Qudit It's open now if you want to add an answer

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Thanks.  I don't really have enough insight to write an answer.  I just don't think that it should be closed.